# How do I get this function to store a user selection and then change the selected seat to "**" to inform other users that the seat has been reserved?

Tags: c++, function, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a function that will:
*Display a seat layout
*Accept user input
*Mark selected values with **

I am able to get the layout to display and the user input is accepted but the selection is not displayed.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int r=4;                        //Global Constant
const int c=4;

void fun(string arr[r][c])            //Display seating layout
{
string seat;
string taken="**";
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    if(i==1)
    {
        cout<<"Next Row"<<endl;
    }
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i][j];
    }
    cout<<endl;

}
cout<<"Which seat would you like?"<<endl;                 //Seat selection
cin>> seat;
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
            {

            for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
                {
                    if (seat==arr[i][j])
                    {
                        arr[i][j]=taken;

                    }
                    cout<<arr[i][j];
                }
                cout<<endl;

            }
}

int main(){
string arr[4][4]={{"A1 ","A2 ","A3 ","A4 "},{"B1 ","B2 ","B3 ","B4 "}};   //Fill the array

fun(arr);


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the checking of the taken seat/input does what you think it does? Have you tried running it through a debugger and checking if everything as you expect after user input? Also don't use `using namespace std;`

Comment: `arr` includes an extra space after each seat name. It is easier for the output later, but `cin` STOPS at whitespace, meaning you can't enter a match. I strongly recommend you learn to use a debugger.

Comment: *"I am able to get the layout to display and the user input is accepted"* -- good. Now take that out of the code in this question so we can focus on what does not work. Dummy up the data from the user's selection, and focus on the final display. (See [mre] and keep in mind that the code in your question need not -- and *should not* -- strive for the full functionality of your real program.)

Answer (score 0):

You have put the spaces in seat names when initializing `arr`. You must be giving input `seat` without space which fails what you want to achieve. Rather print spaces when you are printing your seat and remove spaces when you are initializing `arr` or give input `seat` with extra space. This should work as you want! I have removed spaces from initializing array and put them while printing.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int r=4;                        //Global Constant
const
int c=4;

void fun(string arr[r][c]) {
    string seat;
    string taken="**";
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        if(i==1){
            cout<<"Next Row"<<endl;
        }
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"Which seat would you like?"<<endl;                 //Seat selection
    cin>> seat;
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            if (seat==arr[i][j]){
                arr[i][j]=taken;

            }
            cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    string arr[4][4]={{"A1","A2","A3","A4"},{"B1","B2","B3","B4"}};   //Fill the array
    
    fun(arr);
    
    return 0;
}
```